# safeTransfer with token erc1155 in solidity 0.8

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I get this error
`ERC1155: transfer to non ERC1155Receiver implementer` when try to transfer to a smart contract I found this doc https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc1155 but still don't know how to fix this do I have to abstract `IERC1155Receiver` interface in my holder token 1155

Comment: https://docs.gnosis.io/conditionaltokens/docs/ctftutorial13/
I also follow this doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The receiving contract needs to implement the `onERC1155BatchReceived()` function based on the [ERC-721](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-721.md) definition.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    function onERC721Received(address _operator, address _from, uint256 _tokenId, bytes memory _data) external returns(bytes4) {
        // here you can (but don't have to) define your own logic - emit an event, set a storage value, ...

        // this is the required return value described in the EIP-721
        return bytes4(keccak256("onERC721Received(address,address,uint256,bytes)"));
    }
}
```